# Why doesn't this javascript code to disable buttons work when I use css?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a button defined in html like this:

```
<button type="button" id="btnStart" onclick="startCallMonitoring()">Start Call Monitoring</button>
```

and I use this code to disable the button:

```
document.getElementById("btnStart").disabled = true;
```

But the button is NOT disabled.

Here is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
  <head>
     <style>
button {
    display: inline-block;
    border: none;
    padding: 1rem 2rem;
    margin: 0;
    text-decoration: none;
    background: #0069ed;
    color: #ffffff;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: 1rem;
    cursor: pointer;
    text-align: center;
    transition: background 250ms ease-in-out, 
                transform 150ms ease;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    -moz-appearance: none;
}

button:hover,
button:focus {
    background: #0053ba;
}

button:focus {
    outline: 1px solid #fff;
    outline-offset: -4px;
}

button:active {
    transform: scale(0.99);
}

#calls {
  font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}

#calls td, #calls th {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  padding: 8px;
}

#calls tr:nth-child(even){background-color: #f2f2f2;}

#calls tr:hover {background-color: #ddd;}

#calls th {
  padding-top: 12px;
  padding-bottom: 12px;
  text-align: left;
  background-color: #ff8000;
  color: white;
}
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">

function setup() {
  document.getElementById("btnStop").disabled = true;
}

function startCallMonitoring(){
  document.getElementById("btnStart").disabled = true;
  document.getElementById("btnStop").disabled = false;
}

function stopCallMonitoring() {
  document.getElementById("btnStart").disabled = false;
  document.getElementById("btnStop").disabled = true;
}

</script>

</head>
<body onload="setup()">

  <button type="button" id="btnStart" onclick="startCallMonitoring()">Start Call Monitoring</button>
  <button type="button" id="btnStop" onclick="stopCallMonitoring()">Stop Call Monitoring</button>
<hr>
<table id="calls">
    <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Date</th>
             <th>Time added to table</th>
             <th>CallerID</th>
             <th>link</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<hr>

</body>
</html>
```

Even if I do it like this, alert displays what you would expect:

```
let o = document.getElementById("btnStart");
alert(o.disabled);  // says false
o.disabled = true;
alert(o.disabled);  // says true
```

But yet the button is NOT disabled.  What am I doing wrong?

However, when I remove the css, then it does work.

Example, using same code but without the css:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
  <head>
<script type="text/javascript">

function setup() {
  document.getElementById("btnStop").disabled = true;
}

function startCallMonitoring(){
  document.getElementById("btnStart").disabled = true;
  document.getElementById("btnStop").disabled = false;
}

function stopCallMonitoring() {
  document.getElementById("btnStart").disabled = false;
  document.getElementById("btnStop").disabled = true;
}

</script>

</head>
<body onload="setup()">

  <button type="button" id="btnStart" onclick="startCallMonitoring()">Start Call Monitoring</button>
  <button type="button" id="btnStop" onclick="stopCallMonitoring()">Stop Call Monitoring</button>
<hr>
<table id="calls">
    <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Date</th>
             <th>Time added to table</th>
             <th>CallerID</th>
             <th>link</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<hr>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: what makes you think it isn't being disabled? Seems to disable for me in Chrome (it gets greyed out)

Comment: You are overwriting the button’s style. It won’t look different if that’s what you mean.

Comment: @NickParsons Are using the example with css or the second example.  It does work in the 2nd example.

Comment: @FelixKling Are you saying that click is actually disabled, but it doesn't look disabled?

Comment: @AngusComber example with css (so 1st example). Maybe you think it's not disabled because of the hover/focus styles? You can use `button:hover:enabled` and `button:focus:enabled` to only apply the hover/focus styles when the button is enabled (ie: not disabled)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The disabled function work well. Put a alert when you click on your `.btnStart` and you will see that at the second click it will do nothing -> the button is disabled:

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
  <head>
     <style>
button {
    display: inline-block;
    border: none;
    padding: 1rem 2rem;
    margin: 0;
    text-decoration: none;
    background: #0069ed;
    color: #ffffff;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: 1rem;
    cursor: pointer;
    text-align: center;
    transition: background 250ms ease-in-out, 
                transform 150ms ease;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    -moz-appearance: none;
}

button:hover,
button:focus {
    background: #0053ba;
}

/* DISABLED BUTTONS STYLES */
button:disabled, 
button:disabled:hover {
  opacity: .7;    
  background: #0069ed;
}

button:focus {
    outline: 1px solid #fff;
    outline-offset: -4px;
}

button:active {
    transform: scale(0.99);
}

#calls {
  font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}

#calls td, #calls th {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  padding: 8px;
}

#calls tr:nth-child(even){background-color: #f2f2f2;}

#calls tr:hover {background-color: #ddd;}

#calls th {
  padding-top: 12px;
  padding-bottom: 12px;
  text-align: left;
  background-color: #ff8000;
  color: white;
}
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">

function setup() {
  document.getElementById("btnStop").disabled = true;
}

function startCallMonitoring(){
 alert("test");
  document.getElementById("btnStart").disabled = true;
  document.getElementById("btnStop").disabled = false;
}

function stopCallMonitoring() {
  document.getElementById("btnStart").disabled = false;
  document.getElementById("btnStop").disabled = true;
}

</script>

</head>
<body onload="setup()">

  <button type="button" id="btnStart" onclick="startCallMonitoring()">Start Call Monitoring</button>
  <button type="button" id="btnStop" onclick="stopCallMonitoring()">Stop Call Monitoring</button>
<hr>
<table id="calls">
    <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Date</th>
             <th>Time added to table</th>
             <th>CallerID</th>
             <th>link</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<hr>

</body>
</html>
```

Your problem here is that you think that the button is doing something because of the css animation that you wrote with `button:focus`. You can add specifics styles to your disabled buttons using `button:disabled` css's selector.

Comment: Would you mind updating your answer to show how to edit the css so to disable the animation when disabled.

Comment: You can use the `button:disabled` selector to add specifics styles. I updated my code with an example of UI ;)